# How to use STL map erase from last location in next function call?

Tags: c++, stl

I have this code:

```
bool Sparse_Matrix_RL::removeColsFromRow(unsigned int row_id, std::list<unsigned int>& col_ids)
{
    std::list<unsigned int>::iterator c_str,s_str;
    std::list<unsigned int>::iterator c_end = col_ids.end();
    std::map<unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, double> >::iterator m_str;
    if (data_Matrix.count(row_id)) 
    {
        m_str = data_Matrix.find(row_id);
    }
    else 
    {
        std::cout << "Row not found";
        return false;
    }
    std::map<unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, double> >::iterator m_end = data_Matrix.end();
    std::map<unsigned int, std::map<unsigned int, double> >::iterator row;
    if (m_str != m_end)
    {
        for (c_str = col_ids.begin(); c_str != c_end; c_str++)//col_id's are sorted 
        {
            m_str->second.erase(*c_str);
        }
    }
    if (data_Matrix[row_id].size() == 0)
        data_Matrix[row_id][row_id] = 0;
    return true;
}
```

And following is my function call:

```
list<unsigned int>::iterator direc_Str = direc_dofs_list.begin();
list<unsigned int>::iterator direc_End = direc_dofs_list.end();
list<unsigned int>::iterator p;
for (int rid = 0; rid < total_rows; rid++)
{
    p = std::find(direc_Str, direc_End, rid);
    if (p == direc_End)
        stiffness_matrix->removeColsFromRow(rid, direc_dofs_list);
}
```

I am passing row Ids and a list to function. In function, first of all I am finding that row in map and after finding that I am erasing data from that row while giving it columns which are in list. Now erase function find that location and erase it. I want erase function to start find index from next index each time after erasing one. I want to do it for speedup.

Comment: Is the list sorted?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes

Comment: Can you please add that `col_ids` is sorted to the post?

Comment: @StoryTeller added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `col_ids` is sorted, you can leverage that order and simply traverse the list and map together, like in the merge step of a merge sort, and pick off indices that are matched.

```
auto mm_itr = m_str->second.begin(), mm_end = m_str->second.end();
while(c_str != c_end && mm_itr != mm_end) {
  if(*c_str < mm_itr->first) // c_str smaller, progress it
    ++c_str;
  else if(*c_str > mm_itr->first) // key is smaller, progress it
    ++mm_itr;
  else {
    mm_itr = m_str->second.erase(mm_itr); // They are equal, erase and grab the returned iterator
    ++c_str; // Can also progress in the list now
  }
}
```

Comment: In your else case you can also increment `c_str` since the map cannot contain duplicate keys.

Comment: @john - True. I'll add that. Though it's not too significant and will just cost one extra iteration.

Comment: @StoryTeller tried it. Gives me error `list iterators incompatible`

Comment: @RamiFar - on what statement exactly?

Comment: @StoryTeller the while loop never run. Exact statement not known

Comment: @RamiFar - You just said you got an error. Not that the loop did not run. Please be specific. Beyond that, this may not be a drop in piece of code you can use as is. It's an algorithm for doing what you want, and it's intentionally disjoint from context. You need to do some legwork yourself.

Comment: @StoryTeller thank you very much. You have solved my big problem. Before this work taking almost 9 minutes now it has taken only 3 seconds.

Comment: @RamiFar - Happy to help :)